# The command returned a non-zero code: 2 docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

The following is the Dockerfile,

```
FROM alpine:3.10

# Add the testing repo in case it's needed for additional dependencies
# For example, gdal can be installed by using gdal@community
RUN echo "@community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# Install system dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache --update \
  bash \
  gcc \
  build-base \
  musl-dev \
  postgresql-dev \
  'python3~=3.7.5' \
  'python3-dev~=3.7.5' \
  curl \
# zlib, zlib-dev, and libjpeg-turbo are required by pillow
  zlib \
  zlib-dev \
  libjpeg-turbo \
  libjpeg-turbo-dev \
  libffi-dev
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -q pipenv

# Add our code
ADD ./ /opt/webapp/
WORKDIR /opt/webapp

# Install dependencies
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system

# Allow SECRET_KEY to be passed via arg so collectstatic can run during build time
ARG SECRET_KEY
RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input

# Run the image as a non-root user
RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser

# Run the web server on port $PORT
CMD waitress-serve --port=$PORT performit_15391.wsgi:application
```

The following is the LOG from the server that is recorded, I don't know why the build is failing, can anybody guide please?

```
=== Fetching app code.

=== Building release (./backend/Dockerfile)
Sending build context to Docker daemon    895kB

Step 1/12 : FROM alpine:3.10
3.10: Pulling from library/alpine
21c83c524219: Pulling fs layer
21c83c524219: Verifying Checksum
21c83c524219: Download complete
21c83c524219: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:f0e9534a598e501320957059cb2a23774b4d4072e37c7b2cf7e95b241f019e35
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:3.10
 ---> be4e4bea2c2e
Step 2/12 : RUN echo "@community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
 ---> Running in 42057b30f8bf
Removing intermediate container 42057b30f8bf
 ---> 015ada914599
Step 3/12 : RUN apk add --no-cache --update   bash   gcc   build-base   musl-dev   postgresql-dev   'python3~=3.7.5'   'python3-dev~=3.7.5'   curl   zlib   zlib-dev   libjpeg-turbo   libjpeg-turbo-dev   libffi-dev
 ---> Running in acf5e541c616
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
[91mERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
[0m  python3-3.7.7-r0:
    breaks: world[python3~3.7.5]
    satisfies: python3-dev-3.7.7-r0[python3=3.7.7-r0]
  python3-dev-3.7.7-r0:
    breaks: world[python3-dev~3.7.5]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache --update   bash   gcc   build-base   musl-dev   postgresql-dev   'python3~=3.7.5'   'python3-dev~=3.7.5'   curl   zlib   zlib-dev   libjpeg-turbo   libjpeg-turbo-dev   libffi-dev' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

This above is the log, the apk command is failing. Is there any dependency issue? for me the log message isn't very much useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a version conflict while installing Python. APK package manager supports `python-3.7.7-r0` for `alpine:3.10`. But you have explicitly mentioned version `3.7.5` which is not available. Here either you can go with python 3.7.7 or use a base image which has python 3.7.5 to build your app.